# Order a nested table with path index according to list_order in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, sql-order-by, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have a SQL table with this nested structure:

```
CREATE TABLE items (`id` INTEGER, `item_name` VARCHAR(6), `parent_id` INTEGER, `list_order` INTEGER);
```

My SQLite version does not support window function, currently my query at link [SQLite query](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=94ec2998e83bea42e6a63b85546093ac) are returning as follow the result, but it's not ordered according to list_order, another detail is that the list_order column could come with all values equal to zero.

```
   id      name_item   parent_id  level  path_index list_order
---------------------------------------------------------------
   1        Pois           0          0     1           4
   2        Então          0          0     2           5
   3        Teste          0          0     3           3
   11       Teste 3        3          1     3.1         2
   12       Teste 2        3          1     3.2         0
   13       Teste 1        3          1     3.3         1
   4        Fundo          0          0     4           2
   7        Profundo       4          1     4.1         1
   8        Dhdhd          4          1     4.2         0
   9        Gagagaga       8          2     4.2.1       1
   10       Fsfsfsfs       8          2     4.2.2       0
   5        Profundo       0          0     5           1
   6        Gigante        0          0     6           6
   14       Teste          0          0     7           0
```

What I want the path_index column to follow list_order and level columns, like here:

```
   id      name_item   parent_id  level  path_index list_order
---------------------------------------------------------------
   14       Teste          0          0     1           0
   5        Profundo       0          0     2           1
   4        Fundo          0          0     3           2
   8        Dhdhd          4          1     3.1         0
   10       Fsfsfsfs       8          2     3.1.1       0
   9        Gagagaga       8          2     3.1.2       1
   7        Profundo       4          1     3.2         1
   3        Teste          0          0     4           3
   12       Teste 2        3          1     4.1         0
   13       Teste 1        3          1     4.2         1
   11       Teste 3        3          1     4.3         2
   1        Pois           0          0     5           4
   2        Então          0          0     6           5
   6        Gigante        0          0     7           6
```

How can I align the path_index sorted according to list_order and level columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the column `list_order` in the recursive CTE to create the `path_index` of each item and sort by that:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, 0 level, 
         (list_order + 1) || '' path_index,
         printf('%06d', list_order + 1) path_exp
  FROM items 
  WHERE parent_id = 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT i.*, c.level + 1, 
         c.path_index || '.' || (i.list_order + 1),
         path_exp || printf('%06d', i.list_order + 1) 
  FROM items i INNER JOIN cte c
  ON c.id = i.parent_id 
)
SELECT id, item_name, parent_id, level, path_index, list_order 
FROM cte  
ORDER BY path_exp
```

For the case that `list_order` is not defined for all items:

```
WITH 
  list_orders AS (
    SELECT i1.id, i1.item_name, i1.parent_id, 
           (SELECT COUNT(i2.id)
            FROM items i2
            WHERE i2.parent_id = i1.parent_id
              AND (i2.list_order < i1.list_order 
                   OR (i2.list_order = i1.list_order AND i2.id < i1.id))
           ) list_order
    FROM items i1       
  ),
  cte AS (
    SELECT *, 0 level, 
           (list_order + 1) || '' path_index,
           printf('%06d', list_order + 1) path_exp
    FROM list_orders 
    WHERE parent_id = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT li.*, c.level + 1, 
           c.path_index || '.' || (li.list_order + 1),
           path_exp || printf('%06d', li.list_order + 1) 
    FROM list_orders li INNER JOIN cte c
    ON c.id = li.parent_id 
)
SELECT id, item_name, parent_id, level, path_index, list_order 
FROM cte  
ORDER BY path_exp
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=148c22d73dc4742a9ef11e6750b4c484).
Results:

| id | item_name | parent_id | level | path_index | list_order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14 | Teste | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 5 | Profundo | 0 | 0 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | Fundo | 0 | 0 | 3 | 2 |
| 8 | Dhdhd | 4 | 1 | 3.1 | 0 |
| 10 | Fsfsfsfs | 8 | 2 | 3.1.1 | 0 |
| 9 | Gagagaga | 8 | 2 | 3.1.2 | 1 |
| 7 | Profundo | 4 | 1 | 3.2 | 1 |
| 3 | Teste | 0 | 0 | 4 | 3 |
| 12 | Teste 2 | 3 | 1 | 4.1 | 0 |
| 13 | Teste 1 | 3 | 1 | 4.2 | 1 |
| 11 | Teste 3 | 3 | 1 | 4.3 | 2 |
| 1 | Pois | 0 | 0 | 5 | 4 |
| 2 | Então | 0 | 0 | 6 | 5 |
| 6 | Gigante | 0 | 0 | 7 | 6 |

Comment: Thanks for that, Forpas, But actually I've forgotten to include that the list_order could comes with value zero on the items from the same level :/

Comment: @alexandre9865 in your question you say: *...it's not ordered according to list_order*. How can it be ordered by list_order if list_order does not exist?

Comment: The list_order exists! If the column list_order be with 0 values on first level for example, the order from list_order would be by the insertion order. Do you understand?

Comment: @alexandre9865 check my 2nd query.

Comment: Perfect, Forpas. Thanks for all again haha